# Crop detected Region from image python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-detection, opencv

I am working on a leaf detection model. my model detect correctly leaf from images but the problem is when my model detects a single leaf in the image the code has correctly cropped the image but when the model detects two or more leaves in the image the code is not correctly cropped the image.

correctly crop the image.

[image]

incorrectly crop the image.

[image]

here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
if len(idxs) > 0:
    # loop over the indexes we are keeping
    for i in idxs.flatten():
        # extract the bounding box coordinates
        (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
        (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
 
        # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the image
        color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
        cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5, color, 2)
  
# show the output cropped image
fin_x = x
fin_y = y
fin_xw = y+h
fin_yh = x+w
crop_img = image[fin_x:fin_xw,fin_y:fin_yh]
print(fin_x,fin_xw,fin_y,fin_yh,end=" ")

print("Bounding boxes ")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

print("Cropped Image")
plt.imshow(crop_img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not clear how you want to crop the image in case of two or more bounding boxes. I mean for the image with the two boxes you are requiring two crops or just one including both the boxes?

Comment: suppose when the model detects two leaves in the image then the output should be two images. is it possible?

Comment: Well collect the corners of each box inside the loop, then use it to crop.

Comment: You are cropping and showing result outside `for loop`. That seems like the problem. Likely getting bbox coordinates from another detection.

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
crop_img=0
f=0
if len(idxs) > 0:
    # loop over the indexes we are keeping
    for i in idxs.flatten():
        # extract the bounding box coordinates
        (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
        (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
        if f==0:
            crop_img=image[x:y+h,y:x+w]
            f=1
        else:
            crop_img=cv2.vconcat([crop_img,image[x:y+h,y:x+w]])
        # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the image
        color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
        cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)
print("Bounding boxes ")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

print("Cropped Image")
plt.imshow(crop_img)
plt.show()
```

try this code if any error occur tell me in command section

Comment: error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_operations.cpp:113: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src[i].dims <= 2 && src[i].cols == src[0].cols && src[i].type() == src[0].type() in function 'vconcat'

Comment: the above program showing this error in else condition

Comment: else:   newImg=image[x:y+h,y:x+w]]      crop_img=cv2.vconcat([crop_img,newImg]])   try this

Answer (score 0):

First crop the area selected by you then use opencv to concat those individual images
process shown below:

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('opencv/lena.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('opencv/baboon.jpg')

v_img = cv2.vconcat([img1, img2])
h_img = cv2.hconcat([img1, img2])

cv2.imshow('Horizontal', h_img)
cv2.imshow('Vertical', v_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Horizontal Concatenation

[image]

Vertical Concatenation

[image]